# location.replace to change url after sleep

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to show diffrent urls after a specific time.
I tried this but it looks that only the result of `location.href` is considered (as if the function ignores the other lines), can someone please explain why it behaves this way?

```js
var stack = ["https://stackoverflow.com", "https://youtube.com", "website3"];
function myFunction() {
location.href = stack[0];
setTimeout(function() {window.location.replace = stack[1];}, 3000);
setTimeout(function() {window.location.replace = stack[2];}, 3000);
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunction()">change website</button>
```

Comment: changing the location will load the other page and UNLOAD all scripts on current page. Nothing on your page will be executed after the location change. you would need an iFrame or open in a new tab

Comment: If it DID work, both of the statements would be executed 3 seconds after they were executed

Comment: @mplungjan sounds legit, thank you so much :)

Answer (score 1):

When you run location.href, it is redirecting your user to the first url of the stack, so it doesn't get to run the next lines.